# Force geom_smooth() to plot regression line from origin to one set of points (R, ggplot, geom_smooth)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a very specific situation where I am trying to get a regression line to start at the origin and fit to one set of points on the x axis. Ideally I wouldn't have to do this but  the line from the origin to these points is actually meaningful in my case.

I have come up with a simple example

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
y<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
x<-c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
z<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
z %>% ggplot(aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x + 0, method = "lm") +
  theme_bw() + expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +  
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

[image]

Here, geom smooth will not fit a line from the origin to the points at x = 3. I'm assuming that there is some background script telling geom smooth to not plot a line where no variation in x axis exists. I've tested this somewhat and by changing one of the x values to 0 I can indeed get a line from the origin (though the y value I choose influences the confidence interval which is not ideal).

```
y<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
x<-c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0)
z<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
z %>% ggplot(aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x + 0, method = "lm") +
  theme_bw() + expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

[image]

I don't want to fiddle with the dataset and add a point at y = 0, x = 0 as I'm worried about that influencing some error estimate (however small). I'm assuming that there is some condition that I can set within geom smooth or some other command to force the line to fit. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Hi @Sören Weber, If am correct there is no difference between your code?

Comment: Hi @Quinten, I have just now corrected this. I mistakenly had a 3 on the last x value where there should have been a 0.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that linear regression just tells you the conditional mean of y for a given x. The "regression" at x = 3 is simply the best estimate of the mean of y at x = 3. Since all of your points are at x = 3, the conditional mean of y when x = 3 is just `mean(y)`

So all you need should be a line going from `(0, 0)` to `(0, mean(y))`. It really doesn't make any sense to have a standard error around this line, though perhaps it might be justified depending on the context.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
y<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
x<-c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
z<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
z %>% ggplot(aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x + 0, method = "lm") +
  theme_bw() + expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +  
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 3), y = c(0, mean(y))))
```

[image]

Comment: My thoughts exactly here.  You can alternatively calculate that the slope of the line will be `m = mean(y)/mean(x)`, then use `geom_abline(slope = m, intercept = 0)` to avoid having to plot with another in-line-created data frame.

Comment: I'll try this out for sure, but ideally I'd have some error estimate. In my actual use case the x and y axes are the differences of some measurements that I've made. I guess I could also use model predictions but it feels like there should be some setting in geom_smooth that I could play with...

Answer (score 0):

Kind of silly but workable solution that I have figured out.

If I add an incredibly small amount of random variation to values in the x axis and specify `fullrange = TRUE` within `geom_smooth` then I can get the line to fit with an error estimate.

```
y<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
x<-c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
z<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
z %>% mutate(rand = rnorm(8, mean=0.0000000001, sd=0.000000000001), x = x + rand) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x + 0, fullrange = TRUE ,method = "lm") +
  theme_bw() + expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```